# Dynamic import named export using Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting

Using webpack, if I want to code-split an entire module, I can change

`import Module from 'module'`

at the top of my file to

`import('module').then(Module => {...`

when I need to use the module ([docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-)). Is it possible to do this but with just a single named export? That is, how could I code-split the following:

`import {namedExport} from 'module'`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
const DynamicFoo = dynamic(import('../components/Foo').then(module => {
  const {Foo} = module
  return Foo
}));
```

OR

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "chunkName" */ '../component/Foo').then(module => {
  const {Foo} = module.default
  this.setState({ foo: Foo })
})
```

Comment: what is this `dynamic` function wrapped around import in first example?

Comment: Its useful for code-splitting / lazy loading. Syntax has changed. 
You can read about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: This will import the whole library. There is a not so well documented magic comment called `webpackExports` that only imports specified modules: https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments. See also https://blog.sasivarnan.com/dynamic-import-named-exports-in-javascript `import(/* webpackExports: ["default", "sum"] */ "./lib/math.js").then((module) => { const { default as Math, sum } = module;
});`